# Finite Automaton for a Typing Game

Tags: java, game, homework

I'm creating a game that implements a finite automaton and I don't know if I'm doing it right. Any advice?

**Game class**

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
public final String TITLE = "Game";
public final int WIDTH  = 640;
public final int HEIGHT = 680;
public int LEVEL = 1;
public int FPS = 0;
public int SCORE = 0;
public int LIFE = 5;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;

private BufferedImage textBackground = null;
private BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;
private BufferedImage background = null;

private int enemyCount = 3;
private int enemyKilled = 0;
private int enemyNotKilled = 0;
private boolean target = false;
private String targetText = "";

private Controller c;
private LinkedList<Enemy> e = new LinkedList<Enemy>();
private Enemy enemy;

public void init()
{
    requestFocus();
    try
    {
        spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/spritesheet.png"));
        background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/background.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    textBackground = getSprite(1, 1, 96, 32);
    c = new Controller(textBackground, this);
    addKeyListener(this);
    c.createEnemy(enemyCount);
    e = c.getEnemy();
}

private void start()
{
    if(running)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

private void stop()
{
    if(!running)
        return;

    running = false;
    try
    {
        thread.join();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.exit(1);
}

public void run()
{
    init();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int framesPerSecond = 30;
    double ns = 1000000000 / framesPerSecond;
    double delta = 0;
    int framesCount = 0; 
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int update = 0;  

    while(running)
    {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        //if(LIFE == 0)
        //  break;   game over

        if(delta >= 1)
        {
            update();
            delta--;
            update++; 
        }
        render();
        framesCount++; 

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) 
        {
            timer += 1000;

            System.out.println("Update : " + update + " --- FPS : " + framesCount);

            FPS = framesCount;
            framesCount = 0;
            update = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void update()
{
    c.update();

    if(enemyKilled + enemyNotKilled >= enemyCount)
    {
        targetText = "";
        LEVEL++;
        enemyKilled = 0;
        enemyNotKilled = 0;

        enemyCount += 2;
        c.createEnemy(enemyCount);
    }
}

private void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    c.render(g);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ek)
{
    int key = ek.getKeyCode();
    char character = Character.toLowerCase(ek.getKeyChar());
    boolean result = isValid(key);

    if(result && !target) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
            if(e.get(i).getFirstLetter() == character && e.get(i).getOnScreen())
            {
                enemy = e.get(i);
                targetText = enemy.getText();
                enemy.addIndex(1);
                target = true;
                break;
            }
    }
    else if(result && targetText.charAt(enemy.getIndex()) == character)
        enemy.addIndex(1);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ek) { }

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ek) { }


public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Game game = new Game();

    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(game.WIDTH, game.HEIGHT));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(game.WIDTH, game.HEIGHT));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(game.WIDTH, game.HEIGHT));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.TITLE);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    //frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}

public boolean isValid(int key)
{
    return key >= 65 && key <= 90 ? true : false;
}
public BufferedImage getSprite(int col, int row, int width, int height)
{
    return spriteSheet.getSubimage((col * 32) - 32, (row * 32) - 32, width, height);
}
public int getEnemyCount()
{
    return enemyCount;
}
public void setEnemyCount(int b)
{
    enemyCount = b;
}
public int getEnemyKilled()
{
    return enemyKilled;
}
public void setEnemyKilled(int b)
{
    enemyKilled = b;
}
public int getEnemyNotkilled()
{
    return enemyNotKilled;
}
public void setEnemyNotkilled(int enemyNotKilled)
{
    this.enemyNotKilled = enemyNotKilled;
}
public int getScore()
{
    return SCORE;
}
public void setScore(int b)
{
    SCORE = b;
}
public int getLife()
{
    return LIFE;
}
public void setLife(int b)
{
    LIFE = b;
}
public boolean getTarget()
{
    return target;
}
public void setTarget(boolean b)
{
    target = b;
}
public String getTargetText()
{
    return targetText;
}
public void setTargetText(String b)
{
    targetText = b;
}
}
```

**Enemy Class**

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.text.AttributedString;

public class Enemy
{
private double x ,y;
private String text;
private char firstLetter;
private AttributedString as;
private Controller c;
private BufferedImage background;
private Game game;
private int index = 0;
private int textLength = 0;
private double speed = 0.0;
private int stringWidth = 0;
private boolean onScreen = false;

public Enemy(double x, double y, double speed, BufferedImage background, Controller c, Game game, String text, int stringWidth)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.background = background;
    this.text = text;
    this.game = game;
    this.c = c;
    this.speed = speed;
    firstLetter = this.text.charAt(0);
    textLength = this.text.length();
    this.stringWidth = stringWidth;
}

public void update()
{
    y += speed;

    if(y >= 0)
        onScreen = true;

    if(index >= textLength)
    {
        game.setScore(game.getScore() + 5);
        game.setTargetText("");
        c.removeEnemy(this);
        game.setEnemyKilled(game.getEnemyKilled() + 1);
        game.setTarget(false);
    }
    if(y >= game.HEIGHT - 50)
    {
        if(game.getLife() != 0)
            game.setLife(game.getLife() - 1);

        c.removeEnemy(this);
        game.setEnemyNotkilled(game.getEnemyNotkilled() + 1);
        if(game.getTargetText().equals(text))  
        {                            
            game.setTarget(false);
            game.setTargetText("");
        }

    }
}

public void render(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(background, (int)x, (int)y, null);

    as = new AttributedString(text);
    if(index >= 1)
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.WHITE, 0, index);

    as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 12), 0, text.length());
    g.drawString(as.getIterator(), (int)x + getAdd(stringWidth), (int)y + 13);
}
public double getX()
{
    return x;
}
public double getY()
{
    return y;
}
public String getText()
{
    return text;
}
public char getFirstLetter()
{
    return firstLetter;
}
public void addIndex(int b)
{
    index += b;
}
public int getIndex()
{
    return index;
}
public int getTextLength()
{
    return textLength;
}
public int getAdd(int width)
{
    return (96 / 2) - (width / 2); 
}
public boolean getOnScreen()
{
    return onScreen;
}
}
```

Comment: In the future, it would help if you make life easier for reviewers and explain a bit about [what your code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does). Simple examples of images of input/output or similar is *extremely* helpful, and is likely to give your question more attention.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of things to comment on here.

### Code-Style

Java coding style puts [the `{` opening brace at the end of the line](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#15395) containing the condition/construct that starts the block. Code like:

> ```
> public char getFirstLetter()
> {
>     return firstLetter;
> }
> ```

should be:

```
public char getFirstLetter() {
    return firstLetter;
}
```

Additionally, there [should be an empty line after the closing `}` and the start of the next method declaration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#487).

### Threads

You are using swing, yet I cannot see any places where you are accommodating work that is done on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) vs. your game thread.

This is likely to lead to inconsistent gameplay, irregular timing, and other problems.... especially during the manipulation of the Graphics objects.

### Terminology

I am not seeing a *Finite* Automata here... this looks pretty open-ended, not finite.

### Magic Numbers

These are everywhere. There must be a better way to centralize them.

### Integer Arithmetic

This line:

> ```
> double ns = 1000000000 / framesPerSecond;
> ```

is doing integer arithmetic, in your case, you would expect `ns` to be `33333333.33.....` but it will be plain `33333333.0` because the integer division is done before the value is converted to a double. Consider using:

```
double ns = 1000000000.0 / framesPerSecond;
```

which converts the one value to a double, and thus the entire expresion is evaluated in the double-precision space.

in this case, the loss of accuracy will likely not significantly affect the game, but you should be aware.

Comment: Thanks! :) Do you have any advice on how can I implement a Finite Automaton here?